resize the width of the page in Tailwind/Flowbite
I need the both of the content columns to have the same width as the Navbar.
As can be seen here  the content columns are wider than the Navbar. How to fix it?
Source code

The classes max-w-screen-xl (that applies max-width) and p-4 (that applies padding) in the navbar content sets its width. You can use these same class names in your main content container.
The navbar content also has mx-auto that applies margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto to center it. You could also apply this to your main content container.
Thus, with max-w-screen-xl mx-auto p-4 added:


<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com/3.4.3"></script>

<nav class="bg-white border-gray-200 dark:bg-gray-900">
  <div class="flex flex-wrap items-center justify-between max-w-screen-xl mx-auto p-4">
    <a href="https://flowbite.com" class="flex items-center space-x-3 rtl:space-x-reverse">
      <img src="https://flowbite.com/docs/images/logo.svg" class="h-8" alt="Flowbite Logo" />
      <span class="self-center text-2xl font-semibold whitespace-nowrap dark:text-white">Flowbite</span>
    </a>
    <div class="flex items-center md:order-2 space-x-1 md:space-x-2 rtl:space-x-reverse">
      <a href="#" class="text-gray-800 dark:text-white hover:bg-gray-50 focus:ring-4 focus:ring-gray-300 font-medium rounded-lg text-sm px-4 py-2 md:px-5 md:py-2.5 dark:hover:bg-gray-700 focus:outline-none dark:focus:ring-gray-800">Login</a>
      <a href="#" class="text-white bg-blue-700 hover:bg-blue-800 focus:ring-4 focus:ring-blue-300 font-medium rounded-lg text-sm px-4 py-2 md:px-5 md:py-2.5 dark:bg-blue-600 dark:hover:bg-blue-700 focus:outline-none dark:focus:ring-blue-800">Sign up</a>
      <button data-collapse-toggle="mega-menu" type="button" class="inline-flex items-center p-2 w-10 h-10 justify-center text-sm text-gray-500 rounded-lg md:hidden hover:bg-gray-100 focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-gray-200 dark:text-gray-400 dark:hover:bg-gray-700 dark:focus:ring-gray-600" aria-controls="mega-menu" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Open main menu</span>
        <svg class="w-5 h-5" aria-hidden="true" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 17 14">
          <path stroke="currentColor" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="M1 1h15M1 7h15M1 13h15" />
        </svg>
      </button>
    </div>
    <div id="mega-menu" class="items-center justify-between hidden w-full md:flex md:w-auto md:order-1">
      <ul class="flex flex-col mt-4 font-medium md:flex-row md:mt-0 md:space-x-8 rtl:space-x-reverse">
        <li>
          <a href="#" class="block py-2 px-3 text-blue-600 border-b border-gray-100 hover:bg-gray-50 md:hover:bg-transparent md:border-0 md:hover:text-blue-600 md:p-0 dark:text-blue-500 md:dark:hover:text-blue-500 dark:hover:bg-gray-700 dark:hover:text-blue-500 md:dark:hover:bg-transparent dark:border-gray-700" aria-current="page">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <button id="mega-menu-dropdown-button" data-dropdown-toggle="mega-menu-dropdown" class="flex items-center justify-between w-full py-2 px-3 font-medium text-gray-900 border-b border-gray-100 md:w-auto hover:bg-gray-50 md:hover:bg-transparent md:border-0 md:hover:text-blue-600 md:p-0 dark:text-white md:dark:hover:text-blue-500 dark:hover:bg-gray-700 dark:hover:text-blue-500 md:dark:hover:bg-transparent dark:border-gray-700">
            Company
            <svg class="w-2.5 h-2.5 ms-3" aria-hidden="true" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 10 6">
              <path stroke="currentColor" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="m1 1 4 4 4-4" />
            </svg>
          </button>
          <div id="mega-menu-dropdown" class="absolute z-10 grid hidden w-auto grid-cols-2 text-sm bg-white border border-gray-100 rounded-lg shadow-md dark:border-gray-700 md:grid-cols-3 dark:bg-gray-700">
            <div class="p-4 pb-0 text-gray-900 md:pb-4 dark:text-white">
              <ul class="space-y-4" aria-labelledby="mega-menu-dropdown-button">
                <li>
                  <a href="#" class="text-gray-500 dark:text-gray-400 hover:text-blue-600 dark:hover:text-blue-500"> About Us </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="#" class="text-gray-500 dark:text-gray-400 hover:text-blue-600 dark:hover:text-blue-500"> Library </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="#" class="text-gray-500 dark:text-gray-400 hover:text-blue-600 dark:hover:text-blue-500"> Resources </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="#" class="text-gray-500 dark:text-gray-400 hover:text-blue-600 dark:hover:text-blue-500"> Pro Version </a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="p-4 pb-0 text-gray-900 md:pb-4 dark:text-white">
              <ul class="space-y-4">
                <li>
                  <a href="#" class="text-gray-500 dark:text-gray-400 hover:text-blue-600 dark:hover:text-blue-500"> Blog </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="#" class="text-gray-500 dark:text-gray-400 hover:text-blue-600 dark:hover:text-blue-500"> Newsletter </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="#" class="text-gray-500 dark:text-gray-400 hover:text-blue-600 dark:hover:text-blue-500"> Playground </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="#" class="text-gray-500 dark:text-gray-400 hover:text-blue-600 dark:hover:text-blue-500"> License </a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="p-4">
              <ul class="space-y-4">
                <li>
                  <a href="#" class="text-gray-500 dark:text-gray-400 hover:text-blue-600 dark:hover:text-blue-500"> Contact Us </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="#" class="text-gray-500 dark:text-gray-400 hover:text-blue-600 dark:hover:text-blue-500"> Support Center </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="#" class="text-gray-500 dark:text-gray-400 hover:text-blue-600 dark:hover:text-blue-500"> Terms </a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#" class="block py-2 px-3 text-gray-900 border-b border-gray-100 hover:bg-gray-50 md:hover:bg-transparent md:border-0 md:hover:text-blue-600 md:p-0 dark:text-white md:dark:hover:text-blue-500 dark:hover:bg-gray-700 dark:hover:text-blue-500 md:dark:hover:bg-transparent dark:border-gray-700">Team</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#" class="block py-2 px-3 text-gray-900 border-b border-gray-100 hover:bg-gray-50 md:hover:bg-transparent md:border-0 md:hover:text-blue-600 md:p-0 dark:text-white md:dark:hover:text-blue-500 dark:hover:bg-gray-700 dark:hover:text-blue-500 md:dark:hover:bg-transparent dark:border-gray-700">Contact</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>

<div class="grid grid-cols-4 gap-8 max-w-screen-xl mx-auto px-4">
  <div id="latestEarnings" class="bg-blue-200 col-span-3">Left Column</div>
  <div class="bg-orange-200 col-span-1">Right Column</div>
</div>



